# SSRS default values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Ordinarily, this is a very simple thing. My issue is I can't seem to get multiple values, so I'm guessing it's a format issue? In my report, here are the default values:

[image]

When I preview the report in VS, it shows up exactly as it should, and obviously, I have the multi-select setup correctly:

**NOTE:** *The values of 2 and 3 are the ID's in the query. This is done to utilize the indexing on these values as opposed to just pulling up a big list of strings, so it's finding the ID but actually displaying the "description" in the drop-down.*

[image]

After the report has been deployed, I discovered that within the options of the report (click report, go to Manage, then navigate to Parameters) this is where there seems to be the hang up. I can select just 2 or just 3 and there's no problem, it will use either of them as the default. I've tried various formats to use 2 AND 3 but have had no luck and get the error `The value provided for the report parameter 'Model' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)`. I'm not sure why the default values selection in my first screenshot doesn't take care of this, but for whatever reason, the last screenshot appears to override this functionality. Any idea as to how I might get my 2 values?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Pressing enter to go to the next line, no comma or other separator will get this to work.

[image]

Comment: Also, once a report is deployed, changes to default values that you do in the design are NOT updated in the deployed version. Typically, I delete the report on the server and redeploy it. The same thing happens with linked reports. You can have 10 different linked version of the same base report all with different default. I guess it's this functionality that prevents the defaults from being updated when you redeploy an existing report.